# File upload not working after Glassfish upgrade

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, glassfish

My application was working on JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 6. Application server Glassfish 4.1. I have been succesfully using Primefaces file upload initially. I have upgraded my Glassfish 4.2 and Netbeans 8.2. Now fileupload xhtml is not calling managedbean. The fileupload mechanism has stopped working and no error is thrown, The upload scroll bar moves and completes but the managedbean is not called. I am not clear what could be the issue. Is there a way to debug such issue. To me it seems that http response is not working properly but not able to 
capture it. Please suggest some test which i can try to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Fileupload does not work with Primefaces 6.0 and JSF 2.3.

You have 2 options:

1. Replace the javax.faces.jar file in glassfish\modules\ with mojarra 2.2.8-21 http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.2.8-21/jsf-api-2.2.8-21.jar
2. Update primefaces to version 6.1

The bug was fixed already:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2121

Comment: Hi replaced prime face 6.0 with prime faces 6.1 and it worked. Thanks for the help have been trying this for last one month.